# Cycling on the sidewalk/pavement fines in Belgium/Netherlands

Tags: legal, netherlands, belgium

So, when cycling there is one narrow, but busy road I always 'evade' parked cars by cycling a bit on the sidewalk. I am aware this is entirely illegal, however compared to the alternative (stopping every 30 seconds for the 5 minutes it takes me to get to the end or jumping in front of cars which by law should brake and drive behind me... but they are going a bit too fast for that) it is a risk I am always taking. I do wonder however, how badly would I be fined for this if caught?

PS. The road in question is in Belgium, so for all practical purposes I only care about the Belgium fine, but as I am Dutch I tend to do this to a lesser extent (the Dutch traffic situation is far better) in the Netherlands as well so would love to know both fines.

Comment: This is usually a local matter, and thus you should check with the municipality which you are living in, in order to determine this. That being said, if you consistently have to do this, you may be better off your route.

Comment: @Batman: Both alternatives are worse, one is a road where around the same time all cars stand still (forcing you on the pavement) and the other requires you taking a couple of those elephant paths or whatever they are called in English. Either way, I always believed fines were national, and not per municipality. Quite surprised to learn that.

Comment: It is a shame, I've cycled a lot of western Europe and the Nederlands is easily the most cycle-friendly place, with Belgium coming in second.

Comment: I was recently fined 165 euros!!! while riding bicycle on a road somewhere labelled one-way road. Its incredible! They had multiple signs on the roads, one of them was applicable, so if you are not familiar to the road they catch you a give a ticket, especially to non-dutch speaking foreigners.

Comment: @Ashish: This was in the Netherlands or in Belgium? And you were fined for cycling in the wrong direction or for cycling on the pavement? Or both? Just trying to figure it out :D

Answer (score 4):

Fines in the Netherlands for the two most instances of wrong "place on the road" most likely to apply, are [€ 55,-](http://www.om.nl/onderwerpen/boetes/?&boete_tree=152559,13274,13237,3115) in 2014, although there's always article 5, which says you shouldn't endanger others on the road.

I couldn't find any definitive data on Belgium.